# target/generated-sources/delombok not being added as source folder

Tags: eclipse, lombok, m2e

I set a project to use `lombok-maven-plugin` and it is generating the code into `**target/generated-sources/delombok**` properly.

I don't have lombok installed into eclipse (4.11-M2) with java 11. But I have JDT APT plugin installed.

My problem is that lombok's generated target folder is not being added as source folder into my eclipse project.

I have other annotation processors set in the same project and they are being added, but the lombok one is not.

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <addOutputDirectory>true</addOutputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>delombok</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse fixed it for me.